# Does direct image via proper map preserve coherence of unbounded complexes?

Tags: derived-categories, coherent-sheaves, derived-functors

As for the title, I'm considering a proper map $f : X \rightarrow Y$ of Noetherian schemes and I'm trying to understand whether the direct image $Rf_{\ast} : D_{qc}(X) \rightarrow D_{qc}(Y)$ sends the subcategory $D_{coh}(X)$ to $D_{coh}(Y)$. Here the subscripts means we are taking complexes with quasi coherent/coherent cohomologies.

I know that the statement is true if we restrict to bounded below complexes. The way I thought I could prove this is using the spectral sequence
$$
 R^pf_{\ast}(H^{q}(A)) \implies R^{p+q}f_{\ast}(A)
$$
for any $A \in D_{coh}(X)$. The problem is that this spectral sequence converges only weakly, which means that the filtration on $R^{p+q}f_{\ast}(A)$ whose graded pieces are the sheaves on the $E^{\infty}$ page may be infinite.
In particular, even if everything on the $E^{\infty}$ page is coherent (and this is the case because in page $2$ we have coherent sheaves concentrated in a vertical strip of finite width), we can't claim coherence of $R^{p+q}f_{\ast}(A)$.
Any help?

Comment: According to Hartshorne's *Residues and Duality*, ch. II, Proposition 2.2, this holds if $X$ has *finite Krull dimension* — this implies $R^pf_*(A)=0$ for $p$ greater than some fixed integer and any sheaf $A$, and one concludes with standard arguments.

Comment: I checked out the proposition, and it doesn't say much on the proof. I don't understand why from the fact that $R^pf_{\ast}(A)$ vanishing for $p$ big enough the result should follow. I was implicitly assuming it in what I wrote above, and I couldn't get to the end anyway. It seems to me that the fact that the filtration might be infinite and not stabilise to zero creates problems.